# Oauth2 login for microsoft not working

Tags: c#, mobile, mvvm, xamarin, oauth-2.0

I'm attempting to log into with Microsoft using Oauth2. I have it working with facebook using code below. 
How does the code change for microsoft login?
What is the scope for loggin in? 
Do I need a scope?

```
 var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
             clientId: "MyID",
             scope: "????? What is this for logging in",
             authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=myID&scope=bingads.manage&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf"),
             redirectUrl: new Uri("https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf"));
```

Comment: This code works. I was missing a line of code in another spot. Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Register<MicrosoftAuthmanager>();